# Hikari timeout error during java stress test

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, benchmarking

I'm trying to make a stress test to my simple crud spring boot application but I have got Hikari timeout error. I tried to increase the max pool size but I still have the same issue. If the pool size is bigger or equal to concurrent requests there is no exception but it's too slow.  Have you any idea?

```
app_1    | 2020-11-14 17:20:01.723 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-80-exec-150] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only
app_1    | 2020-11-14 17:20:01.723 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-80-exec-150] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Setting JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(988067110<open>)] rollback-only
app_1    | 2020-11-14 17:20:01.724 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-80-exec-150] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor80)
app_1    | 2020-11-14 17:20:01.725 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-80-exec-150] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
app_1    | 2020-11-14 17:20:01.715 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-80-exec-102] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor76)
app_1    | 2020-11-14 17:20:01.727 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-80-exec-102] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
app_1    | 2020-11-14 17:20:01.727 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-80-exec-153] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor75)
app_1    | 2020-11-14 17:20:01.728 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-80-exec-153] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
app_1    | 2020-11-14 17:20:01.728 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-80-exec-102] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor82)
app_1    | 2020-11-14 17:20:01.729 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-80-exec-102] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
app_1    | 2020-11-14 17:20:01.729 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-80-exec-153] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : unable to obtain isolated JDBC connection [n/a]
app_1    |
app_1    | java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30004ms.
```

EDIT:

https://github.com/wlp2s0/basic-java-web-services

This is the repo of my simple CRUD. Queries are extremely simple and the db is empty so this error seems weird.

Comment: Sounds like your code / queries is just too slow. Hikari has a good writeup about [pool sizing](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing).

Comment: Hi, I read about the Hikari pool sizing and adjusted the pool size accordingly (I also tried incrementing the pool size but the response times are too slow) sadly the issue remains and the queries/code are very simple if you see the code.
They're just the 4 CRUD operations on a simple table with no data processing and no relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently runnign into the same issue. What seems to be the fix is increasing the connectionTimeout.

As you can see in your stack there is a SQLException:

```
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30004ms.
```

This is exactly the default connection timeout value of 30000ms + 4ms (i guess) for hikariCP to get the timestamp at exception time (30 seconds) after the client did not receive any connection from the pool.(Connections can take longer to execute a query than 30 seconds due to network performance, Database overload or maybe even several threads queued up in front of the requesting one, so it times out again till it gets a connection.)

The solution for me was to increase the connection timeout so the client waits longer than those 30 seconds and therefore the SQLException does not get thrown. (SQLTransientConnectionException is a subclass of SQLException)

```
config.setConnectionTimeout(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10));
config.setValidationTimeout(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(8));
```

Here it will wait 10 minutes. If it takes longer, of course the exception will be thrown again.

You can refer to the parameters [Here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#gear-configuration-knobs-baby) for additional information. As you can see it is the "connectionTimeout" parameter that will throw the Exception, what would also makes sense with your error above. I was struggling with this today... good luck !

Comment: "maybe even several threads queued up in front of the requesting one" : what do you mean by this? how does it cause a timeout?

Comment: I have a similar problem as stated in the question, and all of our endpoints take less than 2 seconds to execute, yet we get timeouts. Is there any easy way to understand what causes the connection to "stall "?

Comment: I think what i meant is that the exception might be thrown because there are several other threads queuing the thread pool for a connection. This further delays the connection acquisition.

Comment: @payne Guess you have to actually debug the network sometimes... What could also be a reason for queries timing out is wrong use of the Spring libraries. For example: i did not make a Bean out of the jdbc template object once and instantiated it every time i did a query. This slowed down my app massively causing connection timeouts.